# PostgreSQL use NEW in query for INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql, syntax

I'm having trouble getting an INSTEAD OF trigger to work correctly, and I think I've misunderstood how to use NEW. Consider the following simplified scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
  product_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name VARCHAR
);
CREATE TABLE Purchase (
  purchase_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id INT REFERENCES Product,
  when_bought DATE
);

CREATE VIEW PurchaseView AS
SELECT purchase_id, product_name, when_bought
FROM Purchase LEFT JOIN Product USING (product_id);
```

I'd like to be able to create `INSTEAD OF` triggers to allow me to insert directly into `PurchaseView`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO Product(product_name) VALUES ('foo');
INSERT INTO PurchaseView(product_name, when_bought) VALUES ('foo', NOW());
```

What I had in mind was something along the lines of:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Purchase(product_id, when_bought)
  SELECT product_id, when_bought
  FROM NEW 
  LEFT JOIN Product USING (product_name)
  RETURNING * INTO NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_productview_trig
  INSTEAD OF INSERT
  ON PurchaseView
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_purchaseview_func();
```

However the above trigger function gives errors (`relation "new" does not exist`) when executed. I know I can write queries that explicitly use attributes from `NEW` in the `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses, but sometimes it would be convenient to be able to include `NEW` in a join. Is there a way to do this?

**Current (unsatisfactory) solution**

The closest I can get to what I want is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
tmp RECORD;
BEGIN
    WITH input (product_name, when_bought) as (
       values (NEW.product_name, NEW.when_bought)
    ) 
    INSERT INTO Purchase(product_id, when_bought)
    SELECT product_id, when_bought
    FROM input
    LEFT JOIN Product USING (product_name)
    RETURNING * INTO tmp;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is a little unsatisfactory for several reasons:

1. I need to explicitly write all the attributes of `NEW` in CTE WITH query, which for large views (especially those whose attributes are automatically determined with `SELECT *`) gets unwieldy;
2. The returned result doesn't have the `SERIAL` type `product_id` updated, so you don't get the expected result for:

   ```
   INSERT INTO PurchaseView(product_name, when_bought) 
   VALUES ('foo', NOW())
   RETURNING *;
   ```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`NEW`** is a *record*, not a *table*. Basics:

- [Use NEW in FROM clause in Postgres trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227781/use-new-in-from-clause-in-postgres-trigger/227803#227803)

#### Slightly modified setup

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  product_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, product_name text UNIQUE NOT NULL  -- must be UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE purchase (
  purchase_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, product_id  int REFERENCES product
, when_bought date
);

CREATE VIEW purchaseview AS
SELECT pu.purchase_id, pr.product_name, pu.when_bought
FROM   purchase     pu
LEFT   JOIN product pr USING (product_id);

INSERT INTO product(product_name) VALUES ('foo');
```

`product_name` has to be `UNIQUE`, or the lookup on this column could find multiple rows, which would lead to all kinds of confusion.

#### 1. Simple solution

For your simple example, only looking up the single column `product_id`, a lowly correlated subquery is simplest and fastest:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO purchase(product_id, when_bought)
   SELECT (SELECT product_id FROM product WHERE product_name = NEW.product_name), NEW.when_bought
   RETURNING purchase_id
   INTO   NEW.purchase_id;  -- generated serial ID for RETURNING - if needed

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_productview_trig
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON purchaseview
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func();
```

No additional variables. No CTE (would only add cost and noise). Columns from `NEW` are spelled out *once* only (your ***point 1***).

The appended `RETURNING purchase_id INTO NEW.purchase_id` takes care of your ***point 2***. Now, the returned row includes the newly generated `purchase_id`.

If the product is not found (`NEW.product_name` does not exist in table `product`), the purchase is still inserted and `product_id` is `NULL`. This may or may not be desirable.

#### 2. Skip row if product is not found

To skip the row instead (and possibly raise a `WARNING` / `EXCEPTION`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO purchase AS pu
            (product_id,     when_bought)
   SELECT pr.product_id, NEW.when_bought
   FROM   product pr
   WHERE  pr.product_name = NEW.product_name
   RETURNING pu.purchase_id
   INTO   NEW.purchase_id;  -- generated serial ID for RETURNING - if needed

   IF NOT FOUND THEN  -- insert was canceled for missing product
      RAISE WARNING 'product_name % not found! Skipping INSERT.', quote_literal(NEW.product_name);
   END IF;
   
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

This piggybacks `NEW` columns to `SELECT ... FROM product`. If the product is found, everything proceeds normally. If not, no row is returned from the `SELECT` and no `INSERT` happens. The special PL/pgSQL variable `FOUND` is only true if the last SQL query processed at least one row.

Could be `EXCEPTION` instead of `WARNING` to raise an error and roll back the transaction. But I'd rather declare `purchase.product_id NOT NULL` and insert unconditionally (query 1 or similar), to the same effect: raises an exception if `product_id` is `NULL`. Simpler, cheaper.

#### 3. For multiple lookups

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO purchase AS pu
            (product_id,   when_bought)     -- more columns?
   SELECT pr.product_id, i.when_bought      -- more columns?
   FROM  (SELECT NEW.*) i                   -- see below
   LEFT   JOIN product  pr USING (product_name)
-- LEFT   JOIN tbl2     t2 USING (t2_name)  -- more lookups?
   RETURNING pu.purchase_id                 -- more columns?
   INTO   NEW.purchase_id;                  -- more columns?

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

The `LEFT JOIN`s make the `INSERT` unconditional again. Use `JOIN` instead to skip if one is not found.

`FROM  (SELECT NEW.*) i` transforms the *record* `NEW` into a *derived table* with a single *row*, which can be used like any table in the `FROM` clause - what you were looking for, initially.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tcdbtGNg)

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, it looks like the closest I can do to what I want is (fixing up my original approach in the question):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
tmp RECORD;
BEGIN
    WITH input  (product_name, when_bought) as (
       values (NEW.product_name, NEW.when_bought)
    ) 
    INSERT INTO Purchase(product_id, when_bought)
    SELECT product_id, when_bought
    FROM input
    LEFT JOIN Product USING (product_name)
    RETURNING purchase_id INTO tmp;
    NEW.purchase_id = tmp.purchase_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This does at least make the `RETURNING` clause work correctly. It looks like the attributes of `NEW` must be explicitly declared. The following:

```
-- Using NEW.* in CTE doesn't work
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_purchaseview_func()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
tmp RECORD;
BEGIN
    WITH input  as (
       values (NEW.*)
    ) 
    INSERT INTO Purchase(product_id, when_bought)
    SELECT product_id, when_bought
    FROM input
    LEFT JOIN Product USING (product_name)
    RETURNING purchase_id INTO tmp;
    NEW.purchase_id = tmp.purchase_id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

results in `ERROR:  column "product_name" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table` when the trigger is fired.