# Use NEW in FROM clause in Postgres trigger?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.4, subquery

I am trying to write a Postgres trigger to unnest an array field before inserting or updating a new row. E.g.

```
SELECT
unnest(something)
FROM NEW
```

However, this seems to lead to an error:

> relation 'new' does not exist

How can I use the NEW row inside of the trigger function, in such a way that allows me to unnest an array field for further processing?

**CREATE TABLE statements**

Below are examples of the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    jsonb_array_field jsonb[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb[],
    CONSTRAINT "parent_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE many_to_one_table (
  id serial primary key,
  parent_table_id uuid references parent_table(id),
  subfield_a text,
  subfield_a text
);
```

**TRIGGER function**

Here is the essence of the TRIGGER function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_and_normalize_json() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$body$
begin
    if NEW.jsonb_array_field is null then
        raise exception 'jsonb_array_field is null';
    else
        insert into 
            many_to_one_table(subfield_a, subfield_b)
            select
                parent_table_id, -- this is to be the ForeignKey
                json_data->>'subfieldA' as subfield_a,
                json_data->>'subfieldB' as subfield_b
            from (
                select 
                    id, -- need ID for ForeignKey relationship
                    unnest(jsonb_array_field) as json_data
                    from new
            ) as unnested_json;
    end if;
    RETURN new;
end;
$body$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**TRIGGER statement**

The trigger statement can be run either before or after INSERT and UPDATE, so long as the data are mirrored in the 'migration' table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER unnest_and_normalize_json_on_insert AFTER INSERT ON parent_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unnest_and_normalize_json();

CREATE TRIGGER unnest_and_normalize_json_on_update AFTER UPDATE ON parent_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unnest_and_normalize_json();
```

**ForeignKey clarification**
We are trying to transition this part of our data model to use a ForeignKey relationship rather than JSON field. The trigger is intended as a temporary step to ensure the `normalized_table` has data going forward, while we backfill/migrate data from older records.

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE TABLE` statement and the whole trigger code.

Comment: What is producing the array to begin with? This sounds like a half-baked optimization because you don't want to run multiple insert statements?

Comment: The array is coming from backend code. We have a lot of JSONB / JSONB[] columns in our database, which I would like to move to a more relational model.

Comment: `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense. It's much better to use `jsonb` and store a proper JSON array inside the json value

Comment: Duly noted. I can't change the past decision here, but am trying to migrate the data to a new table moving forward.

Comment: I believe the decision was so the backend could append to the array, as some events related to the table are asynchronous.

Comment: Regarding multiple inserts, yes, we are trying to avoid making changes to the backend code, as the backend team have several high priority efforts currently. So, I spoke with our developers and it was agreed that, during the migration period, a database trigger could be useful to migrate new data to the `many_to_one_table`, while old data is backfilled via a script (which I have already created).

Comment: You added good information but forgot the definition of table `many_to_one_table`. It's still unclear where IDs come from. And it's missing here, too: `insert into many_to_one_table(subfield_a, subfield_b)`.

Comment: Good point. I added the `many_to_one_table` definition above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`NEW` and `OLD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)in trigger functions are ***records*** - each only defined where applicable. (So no `OLD` in an `INSERT` trigger, for instance.) You can perform [`ROW` operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) on them. Reference nested columns with dot notation (like table-qualified column names) like they were tables included in the `FROM` list. `NEW` and `OLD` are visible almost everywhere in SQL DML statements in a trigger function. (Except dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`.)

To treat `NEW` as ***actual table*** you'd have to transform it first - which is ***typically not necessary***. Like: `(SELECT NEW.*)`. For a meaningful use case see chapter ***3.*** in this related answer:

- [PostgreSQL use NEW in query for INSTEAD OF trigger](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144197/postgresql-use-new-in-query-for-instead-of-trigger)

Your basic trigger function burns down to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_and_normalize_json()
  RETURNS trigger AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO many_to_one_table (parent_table_id, subfield_a, subfield_b)
   SELECT NEW.id
        , ja->>'subfieldA' AS subfield_a  -- column alias only for documentation
        , ja->>'subfieldB'
   FROM   unnest(NEW.jsonb_array_field) ja;  -- produces a derived table

   RETURN NEW; -- optional for AFTER trigger
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This was just noise:

```
if NEW.jsonb_array_field is null then ...
```

The column `jsonb_array_field` is defined as:

```
jsonb_array_field jsonb[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb[],
```

It's an `AFTER` trigger, the `NOT NULL` constraint would already have raised an exception for `NULL` in `jsonb_array_field` at this point.

You can merge your two triggers into one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER unnest_and_normalize_json_on_insert
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON parent_table  -- !
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unnest_and_normalize_json();
```

That said, you'd have to do a lot more to cover `UPDATE` and `DELETE` properly. Similar to this one (chapter ***The dark side***):

- [Can PostgreSQL have a uniqueness constraint on array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016776/can-postgresql-have-a-uniqueness-constraint-on-array-elements/8017013#8017013)

Comment: As requested, I have added the table definition, trigger, and trigger function to the original question. The goal here is a rolling migration, so we can deprecate this `jsonb[]` field with minimal downtime or data inconsistency.

Comment: I will also need to get the `id` field from the `NEW` row while `unnest`ing the JSON data, so that I can create a ForeignKey relationship.

Comment: I updated accordingly. Details about ID are still fuzzy.

Comment: Thanks for your help and good humor. I have added a CREATE TABLE statement example in the question for the many_to_one_table.

Comment: We don't currently DELETE rows from the `parent_table` to my knowledge. For the UPDATE case, I was thinking to DELETE matching rows (by ForeignKey on UUID field) and re-creating them from the `jsonb_array_field`, to prevent duplicates.

Comment: This will hopefully be a temporary measure while we transition this part of our data model towards a proper relational model. If we are successful here, we might apply this approach to other places in our data model that have similar implementation.